# Adding new events without removing existing events in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fullcalendar

I am rewriting a scheduling component using fullcalendar, and I think I am missing something. We were initially using version 1.5.4 but have since upgraded to 1.6.3, and the calendar is being included as part of a Backbone.js view. The view leverages a backbone collection, and after a successful fetch updates the calendar, and this is where the problem occurs.

Using 1.5.4, we were able to refresh the schedule by calling 'refetchEvents', which would render all events to the schedule. The kicker is that in 1.6.3 it appears the events are all removed first, and than added causing the entire to schedule to flash for a moment. 1.5.4 never did this.

I dug in to the fullcalendar code to try understand what was going on, and found that refetchEvents in 1.6.3 now looks like this:

**1.6.3**

```
function refetchEvents() { // can be called as an API method
    clearEvents();
    fetchAndRenderEvents();
}
```

**1.5.X**

```
function refetchEvents() {
    fetchEvents(currentView.visStart, currentView.visEnd); // will call reportEvents
}
```

What I want to do is update or remove existing items if necessary, and add new items if they never existed, without removing everything first (avoiding clearEvents()).

Do I have to have to manually track what has been rendered now, calling updateEvent or destroy in my backbone view? Hopefully I am making sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the `fetchEvents()` function, but it may be that `fetchAndRenderEvents()` is calling a [collection.reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset).  Assuming the events are stored in a collection, calling [collection.set](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set) will do exactly that, but then you have to have your view set up to listen for `add` and `remove` events on the collection to keep the view in sync.